# looping through csv file

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and Rstudio. What I'm trying to do is loop through a **csv** file.

The file has 3 columns. 1) user 2) event (success or fail) 3) randNum

So basically every user starts off with a fail and once they reach a success it moves on to the next user.

Ex:

```
user:   |  event:  | randNum

user1  |   fail    |  6

user1  |   fail    |  4

user1  |  fail     |  1

user1   | success  |  2

user2 | ...        |
```

Basically what I need to do is this. I need to store the first random number (6) and than the last random number (2) which will be whenever the user succeeds. How would I do that? And i need to do this for each user because I will be doing something with these numbers.

Comment: If every user eventually succeeds you could just count the number of rows per user. If you use library(data.table) and read your csv using fread (e.g. to dt) the syntax would be dt[, .N, by = user].

Comment: Okay but how would I loop through the table to check whenever a new user has appeared?

Comment: I am not certain you need to loop through the CSV file. Would it be acceptable to get a list of all the users and then number of failures?

Comment: I've made edits to my question to possibly simplify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way would be to use `table` to get counts:

```
table(df$user)
```

Example code:

```
> df <- data.frame(user=c(rep("john",4),rep("jane",3)), event=c(rep("failed",3), "success", rep("failed",2), "success"))
> df
  user   event
1 john  failed
2 john  failed
3 john  failed
4 john success
5 jane  failed
6 jane  failed
7 jane success
> table(df$user)

jane john 
   3    4
```

EDIT: To address latest edits you made that substantially modified the question:

```
> df <- data.frame(user=c(rep("john",4),rep("jane",3)), event=c(rep("failed",3), "success", rep("failed",2), "success"), randNum=c(4,6,1,2,9,3,5))

> library(dplyr)

> df <- df %>% group_by(user) %>% mutate(trial = 1:n())

> df[df$trial==1 | df$event=="success",]
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: user [2]

    user   event randNum trial
  <fctr>  <fctr>   <dbl> <int>
1   john  failed       4     1
2   john success       2     4
3   jane  failed       9     1
4   jane success       5     3
```

Comment: Does that loop through the table?

Comment: Yes it would. I added example code to illustrate behavior.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question it just prints the number of tuples per each user

Comment: It largely answered your initial question. Your latest edits changed the the question considerably.

Comment: Okay thanks I see what you mean now. This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

If every user eventually succeeds and you want to consider the first and last row of every user try following code:

```
df<-split(df,df$user)
df<-lapply(df,function(x){
     x<-rbind(head(x,1),tail(x,1))
     x
})

df<-do.call("rbind",df)
```

From this, you will get the first fail and success of each user

Comment: This for some reason gives the event and randNum in the first row and last row of the whole table to each user

Comment: @jim Yes, the head() and tail() function will give you the first and last row of each user. Isn't that what you need? Just give an example of output that you require.

Comment: okay thanks you! Sorry it was just a dumb mistake i was doing...this is what i need